# How to only allow img-src: data:image/png (base64) in the Content Security Policy

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm trying to load an image in ASP.Net Core that's blocked by my CSP.

```
<img src="@(string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", example))" />
```

Now I've read you can use the following to allow all data schemes

```
img-src: data:
```

Or if you only want to allow SVG's:

```
img-src: data:image/svg+xml
```

Does anyone know how to only allow PNG? **img-src: data:image/png** doesn't seem to work and I can't find any spec on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do what you want.

Current CSP realisation does not support the `data:` scheme with host-part. The `data:image/svg+xml` syntax is [ignored](https://csplite.com/csp/test323/) by browsers. The same is for `data:image/png`, `data:image/gif`, `data:text/javascript` etc.

Valid is only: `img-src data:`

Comment: Yeah I suspected this, thank you for the clarification!